# Iteration vs Recursion question in Lisp method

Tags: recursion, iteration, lisp

I am curious if the following method would be called iterative or recursive:

`(define (deep-reverse items)
  (define (iter things answer)
    (cond ((null? things) answer)
          ((pair? (car things)) 
            (iter (cdr things) (cons (deep-reverse (car things)) answer)))
          (else (iter (cdr things) (cons (car things) answer)))))
  (iter items ()))`

I am confused because `iter` only calls itself with the state variables `things` and `answer` as arguments, and modifies those each run, so that I think it is iterative. It is defined in a method `deep-reverse` that does recursively call itself... This is confusing to me because there are elements both of iteration and recursion in this method, so that I don't know in the end how I would classify it... Is `deep-reverse` recursive? Is `iter` iterative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is `deep-reverse` recursive?

- It is mutually recursive with `iter`. Its call to `iter` is not in
  itself (properly) recursive.

> Is `iter` iterative?

- Its calls to itself are iterative.
- Its call to `deep-reverse` is (properly) recursive.

It is not the functions as a whole,but each call within them that you can classify as iterative or recursive.

As you noticed, the `iter` function makes no use of its `deep-reverse` context. Better separate the functions into distinct `define`s:

```
(define (deep-reverse items)
  (iter items ()))

(define (iter things answer)
  (cond ((null? things) answer)
        ((pair? (car things)) 
          (iter (cdr things) (cons (deep-reverse (car things)) answer)))
        (else (iter (cdr things) (cons (car things) answer))))
```

These are mutually recursive:

- `deep-reverse` calls `iter` and
- `iter` calls `deep-reverse`.

And `iter` calls itself twice.

The `deep-reverse` call to `iter` and both the `iter` calls of itself are [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call): they are the last thing done in the enclosing computation. They are in your terms iterative, though the first does not involve repetition. They could each be implemented as an appropriately set up control-jump/goto. Any Scheme compiler will short-circuit the calls in this way.

The call of `deep-reverse` from `iter` is different. The  call is inside a `cons`. It can't be dug out. It is properly recursive, so needs some kind of stack to carry its nest of invocations.

---

I tested the above by translating the functions into Clojure, a Lisp dialect with explicit tail recursion using the reserved word `recur` instead of the function name. Here is the code:

```
(defn pair? [x]
  (and (coll? x) (next x)))

(defn deep-reverse [items]
  (iter items ()))

(defn iter [things answer]
  (cond
    (empty? things) answer
    (pair? (first things))
      (recur (rest things) (cons (deep-reverse (first things)) answer))
    :else (recur (rest things) (cons (first things) answer))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `deep-reverse` and `iter` call each other, they are *(mutually) recursive*.
Their combination is *not [**tail** recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/850781)* however, so `deep-reverse` is **not** iterative in the scheme parlance (IOW, does **not** admit tail call optimization).

PS. A proverbial *sufficiently smart compiler* (and, in fact, many real ones) *can* compile this function into an iteration (i.e., not using the function call stack).

Comment: The recursive call to `iter` looks tail recursive to me. Translating into Clojure and using the explicitly tail-recursive `recur` confirms this. The call to `deep-reverse` is not a tail call. Are you referring to tail-call-optimisation or the use of continuation-passing style to reduce general recursion to tail-recursion?

Comment: I mean tail call optimization.

Comment: TCO can't turn the `deep-reverse` call into an iteration.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I say in my answer.

Comment: The phrase *these functions* appears to refer to `deep-reverse`and `iter`, implying the opposite of what you intend.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear - I was talking about `deep-reverse` only, `iter` is just a local function (OP should have used `let` instead of `define`)